# Express Heroku can't serve static files

Tags: express, heroku, deployment, routes

Ok so I been working on a a SPA site fora a few days and cant deploy it. I made a slight copy of just to test why i cant serve static files right. 
this is the repo
https://github.com/Pagnito/ExpressTester

[this is what my browser is gettin back instead of the proper js and css files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYN4W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so literraly a minute after this post lol. I changed 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "tester"));

to

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "tester")));

and it worked, now its time to rebuild my originial project and hope it works with webpack, my heads broken lol